# How do I implement a one page navigation with anchors?

Tags: 8, javascript, navigation

So the specific functionality I'm looking for is a link on one page (e.g. drupalsite/home) leading directly to a specific section of another page (e.g. a section on drupalsite/otherpage).

I believe that to implement this I need to use hash based navigation such that the content I want to link to is has it's css class name preceded by a hash (pound sign or number symbol) `<div class="#mydiv">` and is linked to by including the hash referenced content in the href attribute of an anchor tag. Such that `<div class="#mydiv">` on page drupalsite/mypage via `<a href="/mypage#mydiv">`.

Will this work without out of the box with just HTML changes? Or is additional JavaScript configuration necessary?

I know that more specific and fluid implementations will necessitate JavaScript and jQuery, but I want to know if the core HTML works without conflicting with Drupal's internals.

Comment: The target needs an id, not class `<p id="my_target">Link me</p>` and those links like `<a href="/some-page#my_target">Click me</a>` work without any problem in Drupal core. It is just HTML.

Comment: My mistake, I was really wondering if there were any gotchas to this? I know the implementation can be improved upon.

Comment: Actually I've had quite a few gotchas, mainly due responsive images (those have no height set, so the viewport might change when the images is loaded slowly) and due fixed parts (if you have a fixed navbar, it might overlap the top of your linked section). For the first part I used [ImagesLoaded](https://imagesloaded.desandro.com/), the 2nd part I'm doing hardcoded per project.

Comment: That definitely seems relevant and important. Thanks.

Comment: The edit to my title is incorrect. I do not mean "one page" navigation as it is not a SPA. I mean "hash based" navigation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the code I'm using on most of my projects

```
(function ($, Drupal) {
  var wt = window.wt || {}; //just my personal namespace

  wt.getFixedTop = function() { 
    /* return pixel height of fixed elements, e.g. Admin Toolbar or a fixed main nav */
  };

  wt.scrollTo = function(uri) {
    if ((uri.indexOf(location.pathname) === 0 || uri.indexOf('#scroll') === 0) && uri.indexOf('#scroll') !== -1) {
      var selector = decodeURIComponent(uri.substring(uri.indexOf('#scroll') + '#scroll'.length));
      var regex = /^=[#\.\[\]a-zA-Z0-9-_]+$/;
      if (selector.search(regex) != -1) {
        selector = selector.substring(1);
        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $(selector).offset().top - wt.getFixedTop() }, 1000);
      }
      return false;
    }
  }

  $('body').on('click', 'a[href*="#scroll"]', function () {
    wt.scrollTo($(this).attr('href'));
  });

  $('body').imagesLoaded( function() {
    window.setTimeout( wt.scrollTo(location.pathname + location.hash), 200 );
  });

}(jQuery, Drupal));
```

It requires [ImagesLoaded](https://imagesloaded.desandro.com/) and works within and across pages, and with responsive images. It also allows linking to IDs *and* classes by appending the proper CSS selector, e.g. `/some-page#scroll=.my_class`

It certainly is not a perfect solution, but our internal, HTML-trained editors can quickly create deep links to any section they want by adding `#scroll=<CSS_ID_OR_CLASS_SELECTOR>` to any link.